# IV in dp:encrypt-string

Tags: cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, ibm-datapower

I'm able to successfully encrypt and decrypt using dp:encrypt-string and dp:decrypt-data in datapower.
But how do I know the value of IV being used to encrypt by datapower?

Edit- First 16 bytes of the ciphertext generated by Datapower is the IV used. But how do I force datapower to use an IV of my choice over the random IV used by datapower?

Comment: Can you post an example algorithm / key / plaintext / cipher combination so we can investigate? Indeed the [documentation of the function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/encrypt-string_cryptographicfunction.html) doesn't seem to specify how the IV is handled.

Comment: @Maarten - reinstate Monica After some more digging I came to know that the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext generated by datapower is the IV used. I have verified it by decrypting a ciphertext on Java. Now my problem is how to make the datapower use an IV of my choice rather than using a random IV.? I have edited the initial post accordingly.

Comment: Ah, OK. Generally you should not change the question significantly. Instead you could answer your own question or you could delete it and then ask a new one. In this case little harm is done. Upvotes/downvotes could however still be present for the old question rather than the new. It seems however that I'm the only one that upvoted so far. Still: please don't change the subject of your question in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In DataPower, when you use the **dp:encrypt-string** function, it automatically generates a random Initialization Vector (IV) for encryption. As you noted, the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext generated by DataPower represent this IV.

If you want to use a specific IV for encryption rather than letting DataPower generate a random one, you can achieve this by using the **dp:encrypt-data** function instead of dp:encrypt-string. The dp:encrypt-data function allows you to specify both the plaintext and the IV.